# How to paste examples into IPython?

Tags: ipython

The web is full with python code examples that are either taken from vanila Python shell

```
>>> for i in range(10):
...  print(i)
...
```

.... or from IPython shell:

```
In [1]: for i in range(10):
   ...:     print(i)
   ...:     print(i + 1)
   ...:
```

When I want to paste such snippets into IPython, I need to paste them into a text editor, do some find-and-replace and then paste it into IPython. I'm sure there is a better way, but can't find it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `%paste` command works, but what I was actually looking for was `%doctest_mode`. More cool hacks can be found [here](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/dev/interactive/tips.html#run-doctests)

Answer (score 3):

In IPython you can call `%paste` it will paste your clipboard in terminal.

Note: As far as I know you should install `tkinter` for using `%paste`.