# Copying code snippets into IPython / Jupyter Notebooks

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter, jupyter-notebook

Note, my question is specifically about Jupyter **Notebooks.** In addition, I don't just want to run the code, like you can get in the ipython console with `%paste`. I want to paste the code snippet into a cell and edit it before running. (So this is not a duplicate of either [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24242707/how-to-paste-examples-into-ipython) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34861234/python-ignoring-leading-and-in-interactive-mode/34861305#34861305).)

A lot of example snippets in pandas and seaborn documentation have a form like:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'A': {0: 'a', 1: 'b', 2: 'c'},
...                    'B': {0: 1, 1: 3, 2: 5},
...                    'C': {0: 2, 1: 4, 2: 6}})
>>> df
```

To get rid of the '>>>' and '...', I currently paste snippets into a Sublime Text editor, use the multiple cursor to properly format the code, and then paste it into the notebook cell.

Is there a more efficient way to do this and if so, what is it?

Comment: IPython allows you to run code with the prompts in place, but this makes more sense in a console than in a notebook. There's no shortcut to strip them inside the notebook, though there is now find and replace, which should be able to do it.

Answer (score -1):

An easy way to do this is to use the *hist* command or the magic method *%history*

This will allow you to see your history in a plain text format, making it easier to copy/paste.

Docs here: https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html#magic-history

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. The question is about getting code into the notebook, not taking it out.